# Apple Directory / Profile Manager  - Restricting simultaneous same user logins on multiple  machines?

Tags: osx-server, ldap, profile-manager

We are using Apple Directory for internal user authentication. We want to restrict a user to login from a single machine at any one time. I have been trying to find a way to do this in Apple Directory without any luck.

Is there a way to do something similar in Snow Leopard or Lion server?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean Open Directory, not Apple Directory.

There is a check box in Workgroup Manager in the user's account.  Set it to not allow simultaneous logins.  This box is present in WGM on 10.3 - 10.6  I know that Lion deals with workgroups a little differently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a checkbox in Workgroup Manager to restrict Lion users to not allow simultaneous login on managed computers.

- Authenticate with diradmin or other LDAP administrator (the picture below shows the box dimmed as I was not authenticated at the time)
- Select the user in the left pane
- Select Advanced in the right pane
- enable or disable the checkbox for simultaneous login as needed.

[image]